# Postgres jsonb. Heterogenous json fields

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

If I have a table with a **single** jsonb column and the table has data like this:

```
 [{"body": {"project-id": "111"}},
  {"body": {"my-org.project-id": "222"}},
  {"body": {"other-org.project-id": "333"}}]
```

Basically it stores project-id differently for different rows. 
Now I need a query where the `data->'body'->'etc'.`, from different rows would coalesce into a single field `'project-id'`, how can I do that?

e.g.: if I do something like this:

```
select data->'body'->'project-id' projectid from mytable
```

it will return something like:

```
| projectid |
|       111 |
```

But I also want project-id's in other rows too, but I don't want additional columns in the results. i.e, I want this:

```
| projectid |
|       111 |
|       222 |
|       333 |
```

Comment: Can you show what output you expect to get?

Comment: Are you saying you've stored the entire array as a jsonb value in one column of some row, or does this actually represent three rows that each have an object jsonb value? Please provide an SQL statement that sets up an example dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that each of your rows contains a json object, with a nested object whose key varies over rows, and whose value you want to acquire.

Assuming the  `'body'` always has a single key, you could do:

```
select jsonb_extract_path_text(t.js -> 'body', x.k) projectid
from t
cross join lateral jsonb_object_keys(t.js -> 'body') as x(k)
```

The lateral join on `jsonb_object_keys()` extracts all keys in the object as rows. Then we use `jsonb_extract_path_text()` to get the corresponding value.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9abcdd1bcde19edd309fb3b0e10fe2fd)**:

```
with t as ( 
  select '{"body": {"project-id": "111"}}'::jsonb js
  union all select '{"body": {"my-org.project-id": "222"}}'::jsonb
  union all select '{"body": {"other-org.project-id": "333"}}'::jsonb
)
select jsonb_extract_path_text(t.js -> 'body', x.k) projectid
from t
cross join lateral jsonb_object_keys(t.js -> 'body') as x(k)
```

```
| projectid  |
| :--------- |
| 111        |
| 222        |
| 333        |
```